# Creating Secondary Axis in Excel for a bar graph

Tags: excel

I know this might be a very basic question for many of you, but I have been struggling with this basic issue.

I have a data of the following form:

[image]

I wish to have a secondary axis for the C row. I have been trying so hard to make it work and I I have tried the following:

- Click on the bar graph box and choose Secondary Axis from the option, but the two columns end up overlapping and also it affects "all" the columns instead of just C column
- I also tried defining the data set independently into a bar chart with a different names so that excel thinks they are "different" sets, but that does not work either

I only end up getting the following chart.

[image]

Any help would be really helpful! Thank You!